# how to make matlab loop over 2d array faster

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have the above loop running on the above variables:

- A is a 2d array of size mxn.
- mask is a 1d logical array of size 1xn
- results is a 1d array of size 1xn
- B is a vector of the form mx1
- C is a mxm matrix, m is the same as the above.

**Edit:** expanded foo(x) into the function.

here is the code:

```
temp = (B.'*C*B);    
for k = 1:n
    x = A(:,k);
    if(mask(k) == 1)
        result(k) = (B.'*C*x)^2 / (temp*(x.'*C*x)); %returns scalar
    end
end
```

take note, I am already successfully using the above code as a parfor loop instead of for. I was hoping you would be able to suggest some way to use meshgrid or the sort to yield better performance improvement. I don't think I have RAM problems so a solution can also be expensive memory wise.

Many thanks.

Comment: Does your `foo` admit a matrix input, or only columns?

Comment: Preallocate `result`. Change `if(mask(k) == 1)` to `if mask(k)`. You won't get much gain from that, though.

Comment: Hi, I don't think there should be any problem with matrix inputs.

Comment: why won't you give a minimal working `foo` example?

Comment: Also, with the current size definitions of your variables, you should use `A(k,:)` in the code and not `A(:,k)` ...

Comment: @natan I have given an example of my foo(x) function in the above.

Comment: thanks, note that with the code you have now result is not always a 1xn vector, it can be also shorter. See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 result=(B.'*C*A).^2./diag(temp*(A.'*C*A))'.*mask;
```

This vectorization via matrix multiplication will also make sure that `result` is a 1xn vector. In the code you provided there can be a case where the last elements in `mask` are zeros, in this case your code will truncate `result` to a smaller length, whereas, in the answer it'll keep these elements zero.

Answer (score 1):

If your `foo` admits matrix input, you could do:

```
result = zeros(1,n); % preallocate result with zeros
mask = logical(mask); % make mask logical type
result(mask) = foo(A(mask),:); % compute foo for all selected columns
```

Comment: why do you preallocate with NaN and not zeros?

Comment: Because I didn't know which result you wanted for the columns not in `mask`. But yes, 0 is implicit in your code. I have corrected my answer

Comment: its currently failing. i guess the function foo isn't that suitable for matrices. i'll look into it. is there anything that can be done without putting matrices into foo?

Comment: Why is there an extra `logical` in the last line? `mask` is already logical.

Comment: @user2324712 If you need to feed `foo` with each column separately, a `for` loop is probably the best you can do. And it can be parallelized. You could perhaps save some time replacing `for k=1:n` by `for k=find(mask)` and removing the `if`. At the end you would have to "expand" `result`, along the lines of `result(logical(mask))=result;`